# Single-line if-elif-else with list comprehensions

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension, conditional-operator

`item` is all tuples from MySQL

```py
y=[1 if (t['color']=='yellow') else -1 for t in item]
```

output:

```
[-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  -1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1 ]
```

like this one, I want to do this

```
for t in item:
   if(t['color']=='yellow'):
       y=1
   elif(t['color']=='blue'):
       y=2
   else:
       y=3
```

and put the result in an array

```
y=[1 if (t['color']=='yellow') 2 elif (t['color']=='blue') else 3 for t in item]
y=np.array(y)
print(y)
```

output should be like this `[ 1 2 3 1 3 2 1 3 1 2 3 2 1 ]`
How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a great use-case for a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)!

First, define a dict that maps the color names to the numbers

```
colordict = {'yellow': 1, 'blue': 2, 'default': 3}
```

Then, use `colordict.get()` to retrieve the correct number

```
y = [colordict.get(t['color'], colordict['default']) for t in item]
```

The second argument to `.get()` is the default value that it returns if `t['color']` is not found in `colordict`.

Using a dict makes it trivial to add more colors. Can you imagine having to write a hundred nested `if-elses` to support a hundred colors?!

Testing with this dummy list:

```
item = [
    {'color': 'yellow', 'data': 0.5},
    {'color': 'purple', 'data': 0.1}, 
    {'color': 'blue', 'data': 0.2}, 
    {'color': 'blue', 'data': 0.3}, 
    {'color': 'red', 'data': 0.6}
       ]
```

we get the output

```
[1, 3, 2, 2, 3]
```

which is exactly what we expected.

You could also use [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) if you don't want to deal with `.get()`.

Answer (score 1):

```
y=[1 if (t['color']=='yellow') else 2 if (t['color']=='blue') else 3 for t in item]
```